# WUBILDR.mbr file error on windows 7 and windows 8 : UEFI boot

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, bios

0 down vote I am having 64bit windows 8 machine. I have tried a lot, installing the wubi and still it shows the wubildr.mbr file missing during boot. I installed Win7 and did the same, the problem still exists!!!!  My system is ASUS u57a notebook, 2.5GHz dual Intel core i5 processor , 750HDD. BIOS:American Megatrends IncK55A.204, 3/13/2012; SMBIOS Version :2.7 ; BIOS Mode : UFEI

Comment: Please describe the steps you have taken so far. "I have tried a lot" and lots of exclamation marks are not useful for people who want to help you.

Comment: Also: this has nothing to do with Ubuntu so you asked your question in the wrong place...

Answer (score 1):

The last I heard, WUBI didn't work on EFI-based computers, so you won't get Linux working that way unless you re-install Windows in BIOS mode. Instead, I recommend you look at either a conventional dual-boot configuration *without* WUBI or run Ubuntu in a virtual machine.