# Dual boot in ubuntu with pre-installd windows 8 in hpg6-2301ax

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, wubi, uefi

I have a hp [laptop](http://www.flipkart.com/combo-hp-pavilion-g6-2301ax-laptop-apu-quad-core-a8-4gb-500gb-win8-2-5gb-graph/p/itmdgtjcmdusnsky) with windoows 8 pre-installed.

I installed ubuntu-12.10 with wubi.exe, I got screen about about OS selection.
But when i choose ubuntu, it crashes saying wubildr.mbr file missing.

I tried disabling secure boot and tried to install from  live usb but no luck.

I need to keep windows 8 in my laptop as i work as a .Net developer, I have two spare partition each of 20 gb for this purpose in my harddisk.
I want to install ubuntu in one of the partition and use another as swap area.

I am totally new to  linux.
Please suggest me how to do it.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I found this --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/215661/boot-manager-is-showing-ubuntu-winboot-wubildr-mbr-is-missing-or-contains-error

and this --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/247250/wubildr-mbr-file-error-on-windows-7-and-windows-8-uefi-boot

Hope it helps :)

Comment: as i have mentioned i dont want to re-install windows..

Answer (score 0):

Variants of this question have been asked numerous times. See, for instance, [Can I use wubi if I have a UEFI motherboard and Windows Vista?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282068/can-i-use-wubi-if-i-have-a-uefi-motherboard-and-windows-vista/282084#282084).